# Найти изменения в новой версии файла

Tags: php, база-данных, файлы, pdo

Есть две версии файла, старая и новая. Нужно найти изменения и записать новые строки в базу данных.
Сейчас он начинает записывать все строки по новой, почему?

```
// Подготовка к скачиванию
$url = 'http://www.xxxxx.xx/xxx.txt';
$path = __DIR__ . '/list.txt';
$pathOld = __DIR__ . '/listOld.txt';

// Скачивание файла
if (!@copy($url, $path)) {
    $errors = error_get_last();
    echo "Ошибка: " . $errors['type'];
    echo "<br />\n" . $errors['message'];
} else {
    echo "Файл скачан!";
}

// Хеш старого файла
$sha1Old = sha1_file($pathOld);
// Хеш нового файла
$sha1New = sha1_file($path);


// Если файл изменился
if($sha1Old != $sha1New){
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbname = "xxxx";
    $user = "xxxx";
    $pass = "xxxx";


    $fNew = fopen($path, "r"); // Открываем новый файл в режиме чтения
    $fOld = fopen($pathOld, "r"); // Открываем старый файл в режиме чтения

    // Если файлы открылись
    if ($fNew and $fOld) {
        $i = 0;
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO terms(term,value,url)  VALUES (:term, :value, :url);";
        $sth = $db->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));

        // Цикл до конца файла
        while (!feof($fNew)) {
            $newFileString = fgets($fNew, 2000);
            $oldFileString = fgets($fOld, 2000);

            // Если не равен - значит добавлена новая строка
            if($newFileString != $oldFileString){
                $newStringArray = explode(';', $newFileString);

                $term = $newStringArray[0];
                $value = $newStringArray[1];
                $url = $newStringArray[2];

                $sth->execute(array(
                    ':term' => $term, 
                    ':value' => $value,
                    ':url' => $url
                ));

                print_r($newStringArray[0]."<br>");
            }

        }
    } else echo "Ошибка при открытии файла";

    fclose($fNew);
    fclose($fOld);
} else{
    echo "Файл не изменился.";
}
```

Comment: У вас новые строки добавляются только в конец? Если нет, то из-за возможных разных смещений одинаковых строк в файлах - строки будут повторно обрабатываться. И вариант, когда в новом файле нет строки из старого - тоже сделает смещения одинаковых строк в файлах разными и они повторно подвергнуться обработке.

Comment: В случае случайной записи в любом месте файла, советую воспользоваться сторонней утилитой, показывающей разницу между файлами.